# Error installing wpasupplicant

Tags: software-installation, apt

I received the following error whilst installing **wpasupplicant**

```
$ sudo apt-get install wpasupplicant
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
   libpcsclite1
Suggested packages:
   pcscd wpagui
The following NEW packages will be installed:
   libpcsclite1 wpasupplicant
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/847 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,173 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Selecting previously unselected package libpcsclite1:armhf.
(Reading database ... 134758 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpcsclite1_1.8.20-1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libpcsclite1:armhf (1.8.20-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package wpasupplicant.
Preparing to unpack .../wpasupplicant_2%3a2.4-1+deb9u1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking wpasupplicant (2:2.4-1+deb9u1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/wpasupplicant_2%3a2.4-1+deb9u1_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './sbin/wpa_supplicant' to '/sbin/wpa_supplicant.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/wpasupplicant_2%3a2.4-1+deb9u1_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Before attempting the installation I first ran apt-get update / apt-get dist-upgrade / sudo rpi-update (followed by a reboot). These all finished without any problems.

Installing wpasupplicant manually via also did not work:

```
wget http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/w/wpa/wpasupplicant_1.0-3+deb7u4_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i wpasupplicant_1.0-3+deb7u4_armhf.deb
```

Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Why are you installing what is normally already installed? what Distro and version are you using.

Comment: I kept receiving errors when updating so I removed wpasupplicant entirely (purge). I am on the latest version of Raspbian Stretch.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/wpasupplicant_2%3a2.7+git20190128+0c1e29f-6+deb10u1_armhf.deb
apt-get upgrade -f
```

Credit to: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1011008/dpkg-error-cannot-copy-extracted-data-for-unexpected-end-of-file-or-stream